# Commits in the old branch are also showing in the new branch

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I have recently started to learn github. I have first made a branch under the origin develop which is named as branch1 and made one commit. After that i have created one more branch under the origin develop. after that i made a new commit. so, the problem is all other commit from another branch also showing inside that branch. How to show commit which are from same branch only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You renamed branch1 as default and commit one file.

this one commit will be on branch1

now when you create new branch2,it will have old branch commits also in it.

So you need to reset the old one commit of branch1 from this branch 2

use git reset hard

For example :

```
A-B-C-D-E (HEAD)
        ↑
      branch1

After git branch branch2:

    branch2
        ↓
A-B-C-D-E (HEAD)
        ↑
      branch1
After git reset --hard HEAD~2:

    branch2
        ↓
A-B-C-D-E (HEAD)
    ↑
  branch1
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I was looking for this from yesterday.